# External library usage in xcode

Tags: swift, socket.io

I am following this tutorial for import socket.io to swift. http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-on-ios/

I did everything in the tutorial but I am getting this error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'SocketIOClient'

for this piece of code:

```
let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "localhost:8900")
```

My structure:

[image]

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: I can't even read that error message. Please share the actual text from the message and not just a screen shot

Comment: Please can you also include the line of code it's on

Comment: let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "localhost:8900")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make sure about 2 things:

- select "create groups" not "create folder references"
- copy items if needed

Answer (score 1):

In the `bridging-header.h` change this `#import "SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.h"` to this:

```
#import <SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.h>
```

If it does not work just add:

```
#import "SRWebSocket.h"
```

Also rename yout bridging header to `Ribony-Bridging-Header.h` and add it your project's target settings (refer to your bridging header path not just copy "TicTacIOiOS/Bridging-Header.h" from the documentation for websockets).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Make sure when copying you actually are copying the files. Here's a screen shot showing what I mean.

## Don't do this when copying files...

[image: Remember to click "Copy items if needed" and in some cases "Create Groups"]

### In this image the options "Copy items if needed is deselected"

## But be sure to do this

[image]

### Select the option "Copy items if needed"

#### Also be sure to build your project after importing into the Bridging Header file. Be sure if it is a framework to import like so

```
#import <Framework/Framework.h>
```

#### But if it is a stand alone .h file then import it like so

```
#import "MyClass.h"
```

UPDATE: I would also suggest having a look here to make sure you got the steps right - [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)